# upstreaming using fcm in android with xmpp server using php

Tags: php, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement client to server communication using FCM. I am able to downstream message using **Http** post in PHP but later came to know that it was possible to upstream message only using **XMPP**.
Now I read in the documentation about the android client side part:

```
FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
  .setMessageId(Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet()))
  .addData("my_message", "Hello World")
  .addData("my_action","SAY_HELLO")
  .build());
```

but I have no idea about how to use XMPP in PHP. So how could I get started to upstream messages?

Comment: For some context your app server with XMPP will connect to FCM, then your Android device will send upstream to FCM with the code in your question. So you just need to figure out how to connect to FCM via XMPP with PHP. Have a look at xmpphp https://github.com/Drarok/xmpphp